# How to destroy all mongoid database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to destroy whole database through code. I know we can destroy collections one by one. Is there any way to destroy whole database at once?

Comment: `db.dropDatabase()` in the mongo shell.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I wanna destroy through code.

Comment: use rake `rake db:drop`

Comment: thanks @DeepakMahakale its working great